# Why do my draggable snapType: inner, snap to outer?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having a weird issue with my draggable. See JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/c6L9rLxt/1/

My code is:

```
$('.element').draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    snap: ".x-guide, .y-guide",
    snapMode: "inner",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $('.x-guide').css("top", $('.element').css("top"));
        $('.y-guide').css("left", $('.element').css("left"));
    }
});
```

So what I want to happen, is that I want my draggable to snap to the inside of `.x-guide` and `.y-guide`. It does so successfully, however it also snaps to the parent div if dragged close to the ouside of `.x-guide` or `.y-guide`.

The best way to see what I mean is to try it yourself. Go to the JSFiddle, drag the element to a center position. Then try to drag the element to the outside of any of the red lines. You will see that it snaps to the border of the `.container` div. Notice that this only happen when you are close to the red lines. It does not happen everywhere on the border of the `.container` div.

See image: 
[image]

EDIT: Someone wrote an answer suggesting to use Drag function instead of Stop function. It does not help, the draggable element still snap to the edges of the container. The only difference is that the red lines also move. But the snap to the container is still there. That author removed the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is because `snapMode: "inner"` does not mean that it snaps to the center of the div. It snaps to the corners of the div. You can see example here that shows it in a very obvious way:
http://jsfiddle.net/CbESD/3/

(Try to position the red box in the center of the grey box. You will see that it's impossible and it snaps to the sides).

So when in the Question above, the snap-div is `width: 100%` or `height: 100%`. The droppable/draggable will snap to the inner borders of it like in the jsfiddle in this answer.

It does not seem to be possible to disable this behavior. If anyone know a way to not make it snap to the sides of the snap-div, I would love to learn it. But from all my research and testing, it is just the way it behaves.